# Highchart spider web more categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have problem with highchart - spider web. 
Chart works great but i have problem when i want add more categories.
Now i have 8 categories, but i want more, maybe even 100 - 150.
Is it possible to achieve this with this chart?
Below is my chart

```
    $(function () {

    $('#genrechart').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
            margin: 0
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
            buttons: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: '&nbsp',
            x: -80,
            useHTML: true
        },

        pane: {
            size: '70%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 'Information Technology', 'Administration', 'bororo', 'text-center', 'fere'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                align: 'center',
                distance: 2
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 12px">{point.key}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>{point.y:,.2f}</b>',
            pointFormat: '',
            useHTML: true
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sanczopan/qybn6m2u/

Thx for help.

Comment: Please implement your work with http://jsfiddle.net for us to see your problem and edit.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Does Highcharts come with any limitations? I successfully [added a few categories](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/qybn6m2u/1/) but this does not necessarily indicate that several hundred categories will work too.

Comment: hmm its really strange, but now its work. I think my problem could caused that when i create new category i didn't write data for this category.
Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can add hundred of categories if you like, but if there are not enough values in series data array, they won't be shown. So if you want to add a category to your chart, your series data array and category array must have the same length in order to show all of them. If there is no value, just add null or a 0, but it's needed.

Maybe it would be better just not using categories.

http://jsfiddle.net/qybn6m2u/3/

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
            margin: 0
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false,
            buttons: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: '&nbsp',
            x: -80,
            useHTML: true
        },

        pane: {
            size: '70%'
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                align: 'center',
                distance: 20
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true,
            tickPositions: [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 12px">{point.key}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>{point.y:,.2f}</b>',
            pointFormat: '',
            useHTML: true
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },

        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]

    });
});
```

Anyway, a spider web chart with hundreds of categories doesn't seem to be a very good choose of data visualization, but I really don't know what are you trying to achieve, so I guess it's ok.

Peace!

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
In my app i want visualize total count of user track. This tracks come from user playlists in spotify.
So i imagine that in categories i show genres name and for each genre i show total number of tracks belongs to this genre.
Is spider chart good for this purpose? Maybe you can suggest me other chart?